# Runtime error - "Nested Push animation" When popToRootViewController called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im calling popToRootViewController in a UiViewController that is acting as a sign-in page. The method is called once the backend has authenticated the user and will now allow the user to access their account. When the root view Controller is shown again, I get the following two errors.

> nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
>
> Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Here is the code for signing in a user.

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender
{
    NSString *userName = [self.emailTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *password = [self.passwordTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    
    if (userName.length == 0 || password.length ==0){
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Invalid Login Credentials" message:@"Make sure you have entered a valid Username and Password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }else{
        [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:userName password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Something went wrong" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorAlertView show];
                
            }else{
                //dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                //});
               
            }
        }];
        
    }
}
```

The rootViewController is the initial view that the app launches into, and there it checks to see if there is a current user and if not the user will be sent to the login page. I do notice that by going into the Login page, there is a back arrow at the top of the navigation bar to go back to the rootViewController. Once The user signs in, there is now a back button in the same place that wants to take the user back to the LoginViewController which has been popped. I think this is where the issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised when you try to push several view controllers or pop more than one view controller. Are you sure the `viewWillAppear` method of your rootViewController is not attempting to push a view controller ? If so, you're attempting to push a view controller while another one is being popped. Hope this may help you!

Comment: Within the rootViewControllers viewDidLoad there is a method that checks to see if there is a current user. If there isn;t a current user, there is a segueWithIdentifier to the LoginViewController.

Comment: Is there is another location in your root view controller where a segue is performed?

Comment: ViewDidAppear also has the same code to check for the current user. If there is no current user it has code to perform a segue.

Comment: Remove this code from the viewDidAppear, this is where occurs the problem. Tell me the result!

Comment: Your welcome, keep in mind that performing a segue in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear is something you must be very careful with.